# Spark Scala - Convert String to BigDecimal (11,2)

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to convert one String type column into BigDecimal in Spark Scala but in my hdfs directory it is storing the value in (38,18) default parquet file.

I have tried below conversion. Here, the  row is my DataFrame.

```
linenumber = Try(BigDecimal(row.line_number)).getOrElse(BigDecimal(0))
```

Suggest how can I convert `"row.line_number"` value to `BigDecimal(11,2)`.